# JWrapper - cannot find main class

Tags: java, jwrapper

I'm trying to evaluate JWrapper for enterprise purchase, but the app it builds cannot find its main class. I'm using the free version GUI app. It claims to be successfully building my app. The initial launch java app (the Wrapper app) seems to fine, that closes and launches another java process, presumably my code, but then crash. Three Wrapper log files are created, the last being named for my app, and the error I see in that log is "Class not found" for my main class. I have entered the main class name correctly. I have entered the main class name in every possible permutation of the main class name I could think of. As far as I can tell, I've followed all the (rather sparse) instructions on the JWrapper website exactly. Can anyone help me? There's probably some simple answer but I've been struggling with this for days. JWrapper seems like nice software, in theory, but I'm not paying $500/year for something I can't get to work! There seems to be no help available. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to launch the class from the command line using your JAR file then JWrapper will also be able to run it.  You may want to check that you are using dots as separators to the class file rather than slashes, in keeping with the Java ClassLoader convention, for example:

com.mycompany.MyClass

rather than

com/mycompany/MyClass